# Converting long single-line comments into multiple short lines

Tags: sed

I have some lines with very long single-line comments:

```
# this is a comment describing the function, let's pretend it's long.
function whatever()
{
    # this is an explanation of something that happens in here.
    do_something();
}
```

For this example (adapting it to other numbers should be trivial) I want

1. each line to contain at most 33 characters (each indentation level is 4 spaces) and
2. to be broken at the last possible space
3. each additional line do be indented exactly like the original line.

So it would end up looking like this:

```
# this is a comment describing
# the function, let's pretend
# it's long.
function whatever()
{
    # this is an explanation of
    # something that happens in
    # here.
    do_something();
}
```

I'm trying to write a `sed` script for that, my attempt looking like this (leaving out the attempts to make it break at a particular character count for clarity and because it didn't work):

```
s/\(^[^#]*# \)\(.*\) \(.*\)/\1\2\n\1\3/g;
```

This breaks the line only once and not repeatedly like I falsely assumed `g` to do (and which it actually would do if it were only `s/ /\n/g` or something).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perl to the rescue!

Its [Text::Wrap](http://p3rl.org/Text::Wrap) module does what you need:

```
perl -MText::Wrap='wrap,$columns' -pe '
    s/^(\s*#)(.*)/$columns = 33 - length $1; wrap("$1", "$1 ", "$2")/e
    ' < input > output
```

- `-M` uses the given module with the given parameters. Here, we'll use the `wrap` function and the `$columns` variable.
- `-p` reads the input line by line and prints the possibly modified line (like `sed`)
- `s///e` is a substitution that uses **code** in the replacement part, the matching part is replaced by the value returned from the code
- to calculate the width, we subtract the initial whitespace from 33. If you use tabs in your sources, you'll have to handle them specially.
- `wrap` takes three parameters: prefix for the first line, prefix for the rest of the lines (in this case, they're almost the same: the comment prefix, we just need to add the space to the second one), and the text to wrap.

Comparing the output to yours, it seems you want 33 characters regardless of the leading whitespace. If that's true, just remove the `- length $1` part.